# Clustering points on a scatterplot using standard dev

Tags: r, plot

This is probably an extremely simple question, but I haven't found a solution on my own yet. I want to create a scatterplot using random points selected by 'sample'. I also want to group these points into randomly distributed point clusters of a certain size (say 10). I'm trying to do so using a standard deviation, but I haven't found the right method of doing so.

I have the following code so far:

```
max<-1000
MA1<- matrix(0, ncol = 500, nrow = 500)
x<-sample(1:max,50,replace = TRUE) + rnorm(length(20),sd=0.5)
y<- sample(1:max,50,replace = TRUE) + rnorm(length(20),sd=0.5)

plot(x,y, col = 2)`
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I think you should start by educating yourself about [clustering algorithms implemented in R](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Cluster.html).

Comment: I agree w/ @Roland, what you need first is to understand the ideas behind clustering so that you know what you can do, how you'd do it, & why you'd want to. I'm not sure the R task view for clustering will be the most user-friendly place to start, though. Jain has put his old clustering text on line for free ([pdf](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/BOOKS/JAIN/Clustering_Jain_Dubes.pdf)); that might be a better place to start.

Comment: @gung That is a pretty slow download (it's a 39 MB PDF).

Comment: I dunno, @Roland, maybe it's my connection; it downloads in about 2 seconds here.

Comment: I am not trying to conduct any statistical analysis, I am only trying to group the points together. Perhaps I am not looking at it right.

Comment: It's not clear to me what that would mean, @Mengll. It might be worth exploring some of the resources available on the web for understanding cluster analyses & see if you can clarify your question. The book may be ideal (long to read, of course), there is a fairly comprehensive [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis), & there is a `[clustering]` [tag](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clustering) on Cross Validated that may contain useful threads to skim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for equal-size clustering. There are algos that try to answer this question, but the problem is that forcing equal sizes can result in a "not spatially cohesive" solution.

Consider the following case with n=4: X={−1,0.99,1,1.01}. If you want 2 clusters, you get either different sizes or not "spatially cohesive".

If you can live with clusters of variable size, this would work:

```
set.seed=2
max<-1000
x<-sample(1:max,50,replace = TRUE) + rnorm(length(20),sd=0.5)
y<- sample(1:max,50,replace = TRUE) + rnorm(length(20),sd=0.5)

mat <-cbind(x,y)
fit <-kmeans(mat,5) #five clusters, ~= 10 per cluster if n=50
plot(mat, col=fit$cluster, pch=16)
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I need, thank you! This is much better than what I ended up using.